# The intersection line between $2x-5y+z=0$ and $y=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Two planes:
$$
2x-5y+z=0\\
y=0
$$

The intersection line between them would be the solution to that system. We have one free variable - let $z = \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$2x-5y=-\lambda\\
y = 0$$

Then

$$2x=-\lambda$$
$$x=-\frac{\lambda}{2}$$

So the intersection line is given by the parametric equations

$$x=-\frac{\lambda}{2}\\
y=0\\
z=\lambda$$

For $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

The reason I am making this question is because I wanted to verify my solution (it's the first time I do this where one plane is given simply by $y=0$). I found a website that supposedly calculates this: http://www.abecedarical.com/javascript/script_intersection2planes.html but the website outputs the following results:

$$x=0-1t\\
y=0+0t\\
z=0+2t$$

I imagine that $t$ is like my $\lambda$. But even so, the answers don't seem to match with mine. Why is $x=-t$ instead of $x=-\frac{t}{2}$? Is my solution perhaps wrong?

Comment: The answers are the same. Let $\lambda = \frac{t}{2}$.

Comment: Two results are actually the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parametrization and theirs are equivalent.

Yours:

$$ x=0+\frac{-1}{2}\lambda\\
y=0+0\lambda \\
z=0+\lambda $$

Taking $\frac{-1}{2}\lambda=t$, as Tom Tseng commented, gives you theirs:

$$ x=0+t\\
y=0+0(-2t)=0+0t\\
z=0+(-2t)=0-2t$$

If you think of the parametric equations as describing motion and the parameters describing time, you can see that both parametrizations trace the same path (same line), but the website's parametrization traces it more quickly than yours.

Answer (score 1):

There is no unique direction vector for a line. Let $$g:\vec{x}=\vec{OP}+\lambda\cdot \vec{PQ}$$ be the line connecting the points $P$ and $Q$. Then $\lambda$ is used to "stretch" the direction vector so you can reach any point on the line. This means, that if you just change the length of your direction vector, you don't change the line.

More precisely, if $\vec{PQ}$ is a direction vector, then $k\cdot \vec{PQ}$ for any $k\neq 0$ is a direction vector for this line as well. For your question you got $\vec{PQ}=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$. Let $k=2$, then you have $k\cdot\vec{PQ}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$.